# Automated deployment for Docker images which is in php technology

Tags: powershell, azure, docker

I am working on an automated Azure build for Docker application.

I need to connect to container registry and pull the images from container and push it to Docker Swarm resource deployed in Azure.

Can you please suggest me the steps.
I need to automate using a PowerShell script

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Could you post what you have tried so far and what is not working for you?

Comment: As I deployed docker swarm in azure,now i need to connect to swarm using its public ip and ssh key,then i need to run the command to connect to container registry and pull the images from the repository.I need suggestion that how do we connect to container registry with the help of power shell automated script.